# OSM/Google Maps as Base Layer on Geoserver

Tags: url, maps, geoserver, xyz, traccar

I want to make Google Maps or OpenStreetMap (OSM) a base map/layer on Geoserver that can be published, without having to download the entire map, for example by using the xyz tile url service like so:
Google Satellite : [https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}](https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D)
or,
OSM : [https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png](https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png)

Is there any solution regarding this problem?

Answer (score 0):

GeoServer only provides the capability to [cascade WMS, WMTS and WFS services](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/cascaded/index.html). It would be possible to write similar code to cascade OSM tiles but I would expect this would violate the Google ToS (iirc you must not scrape their tiles).

I think [MapProxy](https://mapproxy.org/docs/latest/sources.html#tiles-label) can do what you ask for, at least for OSM tiles.